# Is it possible to inject angular binding into jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I was wondering if its possible to inject angular binding into jQuery. Something like this:

```
$('#wrapperProfilePic').css('backgroundColor', '{{ getCurrentUser().color }}' );
```

Because know when i run this piece of code nothing really happens and if i leave the single quotes out, i get an error

Comment: I highly doubt it. What's wrong with `ng-style="{'background-color': getCurrentUser().color}"`?

Comment: The idea is that there is a div when clicking on it the color picker shows and saves the chosen color. Now in the profile section this div shows again and i read out the color (which comes from the db) like this  <div class="wrapperProfilePic" style=" background-color: {{ getCurrentUser().color }}">. so when the user update the div with a new color. the div on the profile page still has the old color until i refresh the browser. So i thought to solve it with injecting angular into jquery (on change)

Comment: Technically you can. But it is not good for architecture. Consider storing your values in model and updating them by angular.

Comment: If you used @Phil s approach instead of `style="background-color:{{getCurrentUser().color}}"` i think it could just work.